# Avoid from adding event listeners several times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup, window, addeventlistener

I have an Office add-in which can open a popup browser window by

```
popup = window.open("https://localhost:3000/#/new", "popup", "status=1, location=1, width=1000, height=1200")
```

This page is coded by angular. To enable the communication between the add-in and the popup, I have added a listener in the controller. As a result, they can send messages to each other by `postMessage`.

```
app.controller("Ctrl", ["$scope", "$window", function($scope, $window) {
    ... ...
    $window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
}
```

The communication works, except when the add-in changes the url of the popup to `newUrl` (where `newUrl` is another page instance which uses the same controller), by

```
popup.location.href = newUrl
```

**Visually, the popup has changed, however the previous listener is not removed**. As a result, one message sent by the add-in is received and treated twice (ie, by the new page and the previous page).

Does anyone know how to properly clean the listener when the add-in changes the popup page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of Cenk is correct: the event-remove and event-add logic must be in exactly the same function scope.

So, on the side of the add-in, when the popup changes to another Url, I need to send manually a `close` message by `postMessage` to the page:

```
popup.postMessage({ "req": "close" }, popup.location.href);
popup.location.href = url
```

On the side of the popup page, I could remove the listener in the `receiveMessage`, because it is still in the same page/function scope:

```
app.controller("Ctrl", ["$scope", "$window", function($scope, $window) {
    ... ...
    var receiveMessage = function (event) {
        ... ...
        switch (event.data) {
            ... ...
            case "close": 
                $window.removeEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false)
        }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.receiveMessage = function(e){
  ...
}
$window.addEventListener("message", this.receiveMessage, {once: true, capture: false});
```

Comment: I don't know why, my test shows the listener is still there; `removeEventListener` does not really remove the listener...

Comment: can you try this? 
$window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, {once: true, capture: false});

Comment: if your receiveMessage is in controller then every receiveMessage callback is different from other for each controller call so that it is never removed. Your event-remove and event-add logic must be in same function scope.